# Exercise 6.A.17 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler. I am worried if my solution is ok.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, normed-spaces, inner-products

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

> 6.A.17 Prove or disprove: there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the associated norm is given by $$||(x,y)||=\max\{x,y\}$$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

I solved this exercise but I am worried if my solution is ok because this exercise appears to be unnaturally too easy.

My solution is the following:

> If there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the associated norm is given by $$||(x,y)||=\max\{x,y\}$$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, then $0<||(-1,-1)||=\max\{-1,-1\}=-1$.
> This is a contradiction.

Comment: Yep, that's a good counterexample.

Comment: This is correct, assuming no transcription errors from the question. A trickier (and IMHO more worthwhile) problem is to show that $\|(x, y)\| = \max \{|x|, |y|\}$ cannot be generated by an inner product (and it wouldn't surprise me if this is what Axler intended).

Comment: @TomChen Thank you very much for your answer. I am relieved.

Comment: @TheoBendit I am relieved. Thank you very much for your answer and your problem.

Comment: I would bet serious money that @TheoBendit is right, and that it's a misprint. If you want to understand linear algebra, you should definitely be able to answer the "corrected" version.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: The missing absolute values in Exercises 17 and 18 in Section 6.A of Linear Algebra Done Right are typos that will be corrected in the next edition of the book.

Comment: @SheldonAxler Thank you very much for your comment. I hope to finish reading 3rd Edition before 4th Edition is released.

Comment: @tchappy ha  I am working on the fourth edition of Linear Algebra Done Right now. It is still at least a year away from completion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As covered in the comments, you need absolute values to get what is called the $\infty$-norm: $$\|(x, y)\|_{\infty} = \max\{|x|, |y|\}.$$ This is the limit as $p \to \infty$ of the $p$-norm $$\|(x, y)\|_p = (|x|^p + |y|^p)^{1/p}$$
which generalizes the Euclidean norm ($p = 2$).

The rule for when a norm comes from an inner product is called the [Parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) which says that if $\| \cdot \|$ comes from an inner product, then for all $u, v$
$$\|u + v\|^2 + \|u - v\|^2 = 2(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2).$$
Moreover, if this identity holds for all $u$ and $v$, the inner product is recovered "[by polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)" as
$$\langle u, v \rangle = \frac{\|u + v\|^2 - \|u - v\|^2}{4}.$$

So continuing with Axler's exercise, show that the $\infty$-norm (with the absolute values) does not satisfy the Parallelogram law. Slightly more challenging: show that the Parallelogram law holds for all $u, v$ for the $p$-norm if and only $p = 2$. I recommend thinking about an actual parallelogram.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect answer.

Comment: By chance, the next exercise (6.A.18) is "Suppose $p>0$. Prove that there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the associated norm is given by $||(x,y)||=(x^p+y^p)^{1/p}$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if $p=2$." Are you a prophet?

Comment: @tchappyha It's only a norm if $p \ge 1$ (otherwise it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality). Also you need absolute values again. This family of norms (including $p = \infty$) is very common and if you're discussing which norms come from an inner product, you're all but required to include such an exercise or example.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you very much Theo Bendit.

> Prove or disprove: there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the associated norm is given by $$||(x,y)||=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

My solution:

> Assume that $\langle(x,y),(x,y)\rangle=\max\{|x|,|y|\}^2$.
> Then, $\langle(1,0),(1,0)\rangle=\langle(0,1),(0,1)\rangle=1$.
> Then, $1=\langle(1,1),(1,1)\rangle=\langle (1,0)+(0,1),(1,0)+(0,1)\rangle=\langle(1,0),(1,0)\rangle+2\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle +\langle(0,1),(0,1)\rangle=1+2\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle +1=2+2\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle$.
> So, $\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle=-\frac{1}{2}$.
> Then, $2=\langle(1,2),(1,2)\rangle=\langle (1,0)+(0,2),(1,0)+(0,2)\rangle=\langle(1,0),(1,0)\rangle+4\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle +4\langle(0,1),(0,1)\rangle=1-2+4=3$.
> This is a contradiction.